# Configure TFS build to isolate automated tests per project

Tags: tfs, build, automated-tests

I got an issue at the project that I'm currently working on. We run a TFS2013 build using the default template. Output location set to 'PerProject'. The build contains 3 projects.

- Solution A, with two published NuGet packages: V1.0 & V2.0
- Solution B, that uses NuGet package V1.0 of Solution A
- Solution C, that uses NuGet package v2.0 of Solution A

So far, so good. However running the automated test in this build fails. The reason for this is that the default build template copies all DLL's to a single folder and then tries to run the VS Test Runner. This results in NuGet package v1.0 of Solution A that gets copied. Because of this, the tests of Solution C will fail because they expect certain classes / properties that don't exist in package v1.0.

A possible solution is to update the v1.0 package to v2.0 in Solution B. However this is not preffered.

Question: Is is possible (with the default template) to let TFS build run the automated test isolated per project? This will probably fix our problem.

Comment: Why do you use two  different versions of the same nuget in one build? Why multiple solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such settings or any test assembly.

If it can be achieved, so the automated test need to run twice during the build. As far as I know, the automated test will only run once during the build.

So, suggest you to update the v1.0 package to v2.0 in Solution B in your situation.